# Find the most general function $f$ satisfying $f(x)f(y)f(z)=F(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.

Tags: calculus, functions, functional-equations

In solving this (which comes up in Maxwell-Boltzmann’s distribution), we find that on a sphere centred at origin, i.e., for $x^2+y^2+z^2=C$ where $C$ is some constant, the solution must take the form $$f(x)=A\exp\Bigr({F’(C)\over F(C)} x^2\Bigl)$$ And then we notice that this is also valid for all independent values of $x, y, z$.

**Question:** Is this the only solution? Or just some special case of a particular solution?

Comment: Which kind of functions are you considering? Are you looking for $C^\infty$ solutions, continuous solutions?

Comment: @JoseBrox continuous. (I mentioned most general.)

Comment: That's why I asked: a not necessarily continuous function is more general than a continuous one.